# Proof of a limiting distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I have read in a book that the follow should hold, but can't seem to prove it.

Let $ X_i $ be iid random variable where $ P(X_i > t) = e^{-t}$.
Define $$ Y_i = 1 \text{ if }|X_{i+1} - X_i| > \log(n) \text{ for } i\leq n$$ and $ Y_i = 0 $ otherwise.
Let $ W_n = \sum_{i}^{n}Y_i$.
Then $ W $ is distributed as a compound poisson variable.

I really can't figure out how to get this result, I assume the underlying proof should resort to some Stein method or something, but I can't see it myself.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You mentioned 'limiting distribution' but I don't think your $W$ is defined as a limit of something. Are you consider the distributional limit of $W_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$?

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes sorry, I am looking at the distributional Limit of $ W_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$

Comment: Can you provide more contexts about your question, for instance, which book did you encounter this problem and what results in that book might be related to this, etc.?

Comment: @SangchulLee 
It was in Probability Approximations and Beyond Paperback  by Barbour.
Related results are probably Stein's method, and this paper : https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-4/issue-4/Steins-Method-for-Compound-Poisson-Approximation-The-Local-Approach/10.1214/aoap/1177004910.full

Comment: I get it. Unfortunately I don't have good knowledge on Stein's method to tackle this problem using it, but at least I can see that any subsequential limit in distribution has to be a compound Poisson distribution. (So I only need to verify $W_n$ itself converges in distribution in order to complete the story.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Ohh interesting! I am looking forward to seeing your suggestion proof !!

Comment: I added my proof. The idea is fairly standard, that is, we "coarse-grain" the sum by grouping the terms into blocks, and show that the law of each block summand factors into the product of 'approximate jump size distribution' and 'Bernoulli distribution with vanishing parameter'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We claim that

> **Proposition.** Let $W_n$ be as in OP. Then as $n\to\infty$,
> $$ W_n \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi_i , \tag{*}$$
> where
>
> - $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(2/3)$,
> - $\xi_i \sim \nu$, where $\nu = \frac{1}{2}(\delta_1 + \delta_2)$ is a shifted Bernoulli distribution, and
> - $N, \xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ are independent.

---

Let $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ variables, and define the events $A_{n,i}$ and random variables $S_{n,k}$ by

$$ A_{n,i} = \{ \left| X_{i+1} - X_i \right| > \log n\}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
S_{n,k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \mathbb{I}[A_{n,i}]. $$

> **Lemma.** As $k, n \to \infty$ in such a way that $1 \ll k \ll n$, we have
> $$ \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \geq 1) \sim \frac{2k}{3n} $$
> as well as
> $$ \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in \cdot \mid S_{n,k} \geq 1) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \nu(\cdot) = \frac{1}{2}(\delta_1(\cdot) + \delta_2(\cdot)). $$

Here is an intuition: Conditioned on $S_{n,k} \geq 1$, the value of $S_{n,k}$ is realized by a single 'outlier' $X_i$ satisfying $X_i > \log n$. Closely inspecting the contribution from that single outlier, we obtain the desired assertion of the lemma. The actual proof of the lemma is postponed to the end.

Now fix a sequence $(k_n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ so that $2 \leq k_n \leq n$ and $1 \ll k_n \ll n$ as $n\to\infty$. We introduce

$$ \tilde{W}_n = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/k_n\rfloor-1} \tilde{S}_{n,q}, \qquad \text{where} \qquad \tilde{S}_{n,q} = \sum_{r=1}^{k_n-1} \mathbb{I}[A_{n,k_nq + r}]. $$

It is clear that $\tilde{S}_{n,0}, \tilde{S}_{n,1}, \tilde{S}_{n,2}, \ldots$ are identically distributed. Moreover, since each $\tilde{S}_{n,q}$ depends only on $X_{k_n q + 1}, \ldots, X_{k_n q+  k_n}$, they are independent. From this, the m.g.f. of $\tilde{W}_n$ is computed by

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[e^{s \tilde{W}_n}]
&= \prod_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/k_n\rfloor-1} \mathbf{E}\left[ e^{s\tilde{S}_{n,q}} \right]
= \mathbf{E}\left[ e^{s\tilde{S}_{n,0}} \right]^{\lfloor n/k_n\rfloor} \\
&= \left( 1 + \mathbf{E}\left[ e^{s\tilde{S}_{n,0}} - 1 \, \middle|\, \tilde{S}_{n,0} \geq 1 \right]\mathbf{P}(\tilde{S}_{n,0} \geq 1) \right)^{\lfloor n/k_n\rfloor}.
\end{align*}

So, letting $n \to \infty$ and applying the lemma,

$$ \mathbf{E}\left[ e^{s\tilde{S}_{n,0}} - 1 \, \middle|\, \tilde{S}_{n,0} \geq 1 \right] \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (e^{sx} - 1) \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x). $$

and hence

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{E}[e^{s \tilde{W}_n}]
= \exp\left( \frac{2}{3} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (e^{sx} - 1) \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x) \right). $$

This is precisely the m.g.f. of the compound Poisson distribution in $\text{(*)}$, hence we know that the claim holds with $\tilde{W}_n$ in place of $W_n$.

Finally, noting that $\mathbf{E}[\mathbb{I}[A_{n,1}]] = \frac{1}{n}$ and

$$ W_n - \tilde{W}_n = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/k_n\rfloor -1} \mathbf{1}[A_{n,k_n q}] + \sum_{i = \lfloor n/k_n\rfloor k_n}^{n} \mathbf{1}[A_{n,i}], $$

we have

$$ \mathbf{E}[|W_n - \tilde{W}_n|]
\leq \frac{\lfloor n/k_n\rfloor}{n} + \frac{k_n}{n}
\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0. $$

This implies that $W_n$ and $\tilde{W}_n$ converges to the same limit in distribution, and therefore the desired claim follows. $\square$

---

*Proof of Lemma.* In order to have $S_{n,k} \geq 1$, at least one of $X_1, \ldots, X_{k+1}$ must be at least $\log n$. Let $\mathcal{I}_{n,k}$ be a random index set defined by

$$ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = \{ i \in [k+1] : X_i > \log n\}, $$

where $[k+1] = \{1,2,\ldots,k+1\}$. Then for each $E \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E )
= \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E , \  \mathcal{I}_{n,k} \neq \varnothing ) 
= \sum_{\substack{I \subseteq [k+1] \\ I \neq \varnothing}} \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E , \ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = I ).
\end{align*}

However, for each non-empty $I \subseteq [k+1]$, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E , \ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = I )
\leq \mathbf{P}( I \subseteq \mathcal{I}_{n,k} )
= \mathbf{P}(\cap_{i \in I} \{ X_i > \log n \})
= \frac{1}{n^{|I|}}.
\end{align*}

Plugging this bound into the sum above, for $1 \leq k \leq n$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\left| \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E )
- \sum_{i=2}^{k} \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E , \ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = \{i\} ) \right|
&\leq \frac{2}{n} + \sum_{j=2}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j}\frac{1}{n^j} \\
&\leq C\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right) \tag{L.1}
\end{align*}

for some absolute constant $C > 0$. On the other hand, when $\mathcal{I}_{n,k} = \{i\}$ is a singleton, then only $\mathbb{I}[A_{n,i-1}]$ and $\mathbb{I}[A_{n,i}]$ can contribute to the value of the sum $S_{n,k}$. So, if $2 \leq i \leq k$, then by the symmetry,

\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E , \ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = \{i\} ) \\
&= \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E , \ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = \{2\} )\\
&= \mathbf{P}( \mathbb{I}[A_{n,1}] + \mathbb{I}[A_{n,2}] \in E, \ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = \{2\} ) \\
&= \mathbf{P}( \mathbb{I}[A_{n,1}] + \mathbb{I}[A_{n,2}] \in E , \ X_1, X_3 \leq \log n \mid X_2 > \log n ) \\
&\quad \times \mathbf{P}(X_2 > \log n) \mathbf{P}(\cap_{j=4}^{k+1} \{ X_j \leq \log n\}).
\end{align*}

So by writing $\tilde{X}_2 = X_2 - \log n$, then the law of $\tilde{X}_2$ conditioned on $\{X_2 > \log n\}$ is again $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ by the memorylessness property, and so,

\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E , \ \mathcal{I}_{n,k} = \{i\} ) \\
&= \mathbf{P}( \mathbb{I}[X_2 > X_1] + \mathbb{I}[X_2 > X_3] \in E , \ X_1, X_3 \leq \log n ) \frac{(1 - \frac{1}{n})^{k-2}}{n}. \tag{L.2}
\end{align*}

So, using $\text{(L.1)}$ and $\text{(L.2)}$ and noting that

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}( \mathbb{I}[X_2 > X_1] + \mathbb{I}[X_2 > X_3] = s , \ X_1, X_3 \leq \log n )
= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right), & \text{if } s = 1, 2, \\
0, & \text{if } s \geq 3.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

we conclude

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} = s )
= \begin{cases}
\frac{k-1}{n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{k-2} \left( \frac{1}{3} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right), & \text{if } s = 1, 2, \\
\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right), & \text{if } s \geq 3.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Now combining altogether, we find that

$$ \mathbf{P}( S_{n,k} \in E \mid S_{n,k} \geq 1)
= \frac{ \delta_{1}(E) + \delta_2(E) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon_{n,k})}{2 + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon_{n,k})}, $$

where $\varepsilon_{n,k}$ takes the form

$$ \varepsilon_{n,k} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\frac{1}{k}+\frac{k}{n}}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{k-2}}. $$

Since $\varepsilon_{n,k} \to 0$ as $k, n \to \infty$ in such a way that $1 \ll k \ll n$, the desired claim follows. $\square$

Comment: This is really amazing! I love it. If I figure out something with Stein's method, I will post to you!